# How to start Punjab server on Windows?

Tags: xmpp, punjab

On Windows, I have installed punjab using "python setup.py install", but when I am trying to start using "twistd -y punjab" it says "twistd is not recognized as an internal or external command", so I added env variable PATH pointing to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts", but after that if I am trying the command "twistd -y punjab", it simply opens the twistd.py file present at the path I added to PATH env variable.

Can anyone tell me how to start the punjab bosh server??

Answer (score 0):

Your env variables are not valid. You need to double check on the same.

Make sure you have C:\Python27\Scripts value inside path variable. (assuming C:\Python27\ is your root)

Comment: A more useful answer would provide more explanation.